# Returning results from a date range search in Meteor

Tags: mongodb, meteor, mongodb-query

Inside of my Meteor.users collection I have an array of objects which looks like this:

[image]

I need to search through all of these for all users and then return the objects where the `timestamp` is within the date range I specify.

I have tried doing this, but it returns the entire users object instead of the specific objects within `shortURLs` that are between my specified dates:

`Meteor.users.find({'shortURLs.timestamp': { $gte : new Date(1478995200000), $lt: new Date(1479254400000) } }).fetch();`

I have also tried this, which gives me an array of all the objects in `shortURLs` for those users, and unfortunately not just the ones that are between the specified dates (I am using [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/) for _.chain):

```
var start = new Date(1478995200000);
var end = new Date(1479254400000);
_.chain(Meteor.users.find({'shortURLs.timestamp': { $gte : start, $lt: end } }).map(function (users) { return { url: users.shortURLs} })).pluck('url').flatten().uniq().value();
```

Any assistance with this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a *projection* to limit the results returned from the subdocument to those that match your query.

```
let start = new Date(1478995200000), end = new Date(1479254400000);
let results = Meteor.users.find(
  { 'shortURLs.timestamp': { $gte: start , $lt: end }},
  { fields: { shortURLs: { $elemMatch: { timestamp: { $gte: start , $lt: end }}}}}
  ).fetch();
```

If I wanted to do this even more compactly I would reuse the query as the projection as follows:

```
let start = new Date(1478995200000), end = new Date(1479254400000);
let query = { shortURLs: { $elemMatch: { timestamp: { $gte: start , $lt: end }}}};
let projection = { fields: query };
let results = Meteor.users.find(query,projection).fetch();
```

The projection basically says *after you find the matching documents only give me back what is specified in the projection*.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply. I've given this a try but it seems to be giving me the same result as my first example in my post, where it returns the full user object for any users that have a `shortURLs.timestamp` which fit in with the search query. I used your example and specify the field that way it only returns the `shortURLs` but even if I go into `shortURLs` it's still listing all of the objects that exist, even the ones which do not fall into the date range that's specified. Here's a [screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/Lg8Wznf.png) if I put it in my console for example.

Comment: Interesting, it's projecting the fields correctly by only including the `shortURLs` key but not filtering that array. Is the result returning the right documents? (i.e. only those that have a date in the range?)

Comment: Found a clue at https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/6084 I was missing the `fields` qualifier in the projection.

Comment: Unfortunately this is returning: "Uncaught Error: Minimongo doesn't support operators in projections yet."

Comment: If I put that in a Meteor shell I can receive a result in there, but it's a bit strange. It seems to be returning each user object that has an object inside of `shortURLs` which is within the start/end date, but it also seems to only be showing one object inside of `shortURLs` for each one, and that one appears to be whichever is closest to the `$gte` (oldest) date. Here's a [screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/KOUIACL.png)  showing this.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how it works... Mongo will return you user records if ANY of the shortURL's match your criteria. And as you have observed, it gives you the entire user record without filtering the array of shortURLs.

The way you have structured your data doesn't make it easy to do this. Either you do the query, and then iterate over the data to extract just what you want, or you restructure your data to put shortURLs in  a separate collection, with a reference to the userid in each record. If you do it that way, it becomes very easy (and efficient) to get what you want.

The Meteor users collection is kind of special, and it's not recommended to put additional data in it, as it gets re-written when the user gets a new login token. So it's probably a good idea to pull out this data into another collection, especially if you want to timestamp the records when they are written.